# metric signature

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

What can be the rank and signature of the restriction of a non-degenerate real quadratic form $q$ of signature $(,)$ to a vector subspace $U$ of codimension $1$?

My attempt. The Gram matrix $Q$ of $q$ is diagonable. 
$$ Q = \begin{pmatrix}\lambda_{1}  \\ & \lambda_{2} \\ & & \ddots  \\ & & & \lambda_{p} \\ & & & & \mu_{1}\\ &&&&&\mu_{2} \\ & &&&&& \ddots\\&&&&&&& \mu_{m} \end{pmatrix}, \lambda_{i}>0,\mu_{j}<0.$$
$\exists ! F_{q}: q(v)=(v,F_{q}(v)) $.

1. Let $v$ be an an eigenvector $v:F_{q} (v)=\lambda_{i}v$ then $rk(q|_{v^{\bot}})=p+m-1$ and the signature is $(p-1,m)$ or $(p,m-1)$.
2. $U \neq v^{\bot}$ for any  eigenvector of $F_{q}$.
   $$Q \sim Q_{u} = \begin{pmatrix} a_{1}& 0 &\cdots & 0 & a_{1n}  \\ 0 & a_{2} &&\vdots & a_{2n}\\ \vdots & & \ddots & 0 & \vdots \\ 0 & \cdots  & 0 & a_{n-1}\\a_{1n} &a_{2n}& \cdots && a_{n} \end{pmatrix}.$$

I tried to solve the problem when $a_{1}\cdot a_{2}\cdots \cdots a_{n-1} \ne 0$. I used   Gaussian elimination for quadratic forms to diagonalize $ Q_{u}$ to see the connection between $a_{i}$ and $\lambda,\mu$.

The result: $\{a_{1},...,a_{n-1}, a_{n}-a_{1n}^{2}/a_{11}-...-a_{1,n-1}^2/a_{n-1}\}=\{\lambda_{1},...,\lambda_{p},\mu_{1},..., \mu_{m}\}$.  Something wrong with it...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand at all what you tried to do, the answer is much simpler.

Take $H=U^\perp$ the line orthogonal to $U$ with respect to $q$, and diagonalize $q$ on both $U$ and $H$: $q_{|U}\simeq \langle a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}\rangle$ and $q_{|H}\simeq \langle b\rangle$ where $n$ is the dimension of the whole space. Since $q=q_{|U}\perp q_{|H}$ You can clearly see the link between the signatures of $q$ and $q_{|U}$ depending on the sign of $b$.

Comment: $F_{q}: q(v)=(v,F_{q}(v)$ has only $n$ eigenvectors.  $\{a_{1},...,b\}$ - eigenvalues of $F_{q}$. Does it mean that we can choose a basis  of $U$ which consists of $n-1$ eigenvectors?

Comment: Yes. Unlike restriction of endomorphisms, restriction of quadratic forms is extremely well-behaved. When you restrict $q$ to $U$, you get an honest quadratic form, which you can diagonalize like any other quadratic form.